# Как в Python разделить строку на значения и записать их в массив?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть строка с определенным форматом:

```
"Значение 1, Значение 2, Значение 3"
```

Как разделить эту строку на значения, убрав запятые с пробелами между ними, чтобы получился такой массив:?

```
["Значение 1", "Значение 2", "Значение 3"]
```

Comment: Ну элементарно же, `text.split(", ")`

Comment: text.split(", "), причем ", " это строка по которой происходит разделение. Можете написать ",", а потом для каждого элмента удалить начальные и конечные пробелы.

А вообще раз есть такой вопрос, то советую просто открыть страничку "текстовые функции в python"

Answer (score 2):

Вот так, с помощью `split`:

```py
string = "Значение 1, Значение 2, Значение 3"
lst = string.split(", ")
print(lst)
```

Вот вывод:

```py
['Значение 1', 'Значение 2', 'Значение 3']
```

Про `split` можно почитать в [документации](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split).